# Qt3 Работа с QTable

Tags: c++, qt

[image: СХема]
Добрый день!
Нужна помощь
Работаю на Qt3 из-за необходимости
Имеется таблица,которая заполняется элементами из БД
Есть так же два SpinBox'а
Таблица представлена на рисунке, проблема вот в чем: как с помощью данных SpinBox'ов изменять количество строк, но не тривиальным образом, то есть если меняется SpinBox1 , то добавляется общее кол-во строк, а если изменяется SpinBox2, то в первой колонке кол-во строк не меняется, а меняется только все остальные,а первая расширяется , и далее если снова изменяется SpinBox1, то добавляется общее кол-во строк, но если ширина первой строки первой колонки была 2 строки других колонок, то она так же должна сохраняться.
Думаю на рисунке более понятно,что требуется

upd
Обновил схему,думаю так понятнее в чем проблема.
Попытался как то через setSpan это сделать, но изначально это была утопическая мысль. Наверно все таки из коробки это сделать не выйдет в Qt3

Comment: Конкретики не много и я не уверен, что в точности понял, что именно ты пытаешься сделать, но ЕМНИП в тройке никаких вкусностей вроде model-view не было, так что скорей всего придётся всё делать ручками, при этом отнаследовавшись от QTableView или QDataTable... Реализацию последнего стоит предварительно  изучить...

Comment: А ещё QTable в принципе не поддерживает многострочные ячейки... Поэтому, всё очень печально: если оное действительно нужно, то скорей всего придётся весь табличный виджет писать с нуля или как-то хитро наследовать с замазыванием линий.